# Windows 7 Home Premium always claims it was not shut down properly

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I have Windows 7 Home Premium, and no matter if I shut down my computer or put it to sleep (the proper way using the start button or just by shutting the lid), every time when starting back up there is a message that Windows was not shut down properly.

This error causes my computer to restart verrrry slowllly and I would really like to fix it!

I have tried updating, but no luck! Any suggestions, please?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a driver issue if shutting your lid doesn't work the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like drive volume's "dirty-bit" is set.

> If a volume's dirty bit is set, this indicates that the file system
>   may be in an inconsistent state. The dirty bit can be set because the
>   volume is online and has outstanding changes, because changes were
>   made to the volume and the computer shutdown before the changes were
>   committed to disk, or because corruption was detected on the volume.
>   If the dirty bit is set when the computer restarts, chkdsk runs to
>   verify the consistency of the volume.
>
> Every time Windows starts, Autochk.exe is called by the Kernel to
>   scan all volumes to check if the volume dirty bit is set. If the dirty
>   bit is set, autochk performs an immediate chkdsk /f on that volume.
>   Chkdsk /f verifies file system integrity and attempts to fix any
>   problems with the volume.

First I would try running chkdsk manually from the cmd prompt: `chkdsk C: /f /r` which will check disk and attempt to repair any problems it finds. If that doesn't fix things,  and you're at least fairly sure the computer isn't getting shutdown improperly, you can disable the dirty-bit checking by using Window's [chkntfs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160963) command.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try all these steps today!